# Call Dictionary With Randomly Chosen Value as Name - TypeError

Tags: python, dictionary, call

I am using a function that assigns a variable to equal the value of a randomly chosen key. Here the type is string and print works.

```
def explore():
    import random
    random_key = random.choice(explore_items.keys())
    found_item = explore_items[random_key]
    print type(found_item)
    print found_item
```

Then, I want to use the variable name 'found_item' to call a dictionary of the same name, eg:

`print found_item['key_1']`

But I get the error, "TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str"

How would I use a string to call a previously defined dictionary that shares the same name?

Comment: `found_item` is a string, not a dictionary.

Comment: What do you mean you want to randomly take a value from a dictionary or what because if it's that then you can use random.choice(dictionay_name)

Comment: It sounds like your question is really about dynamically accessing a variable whose name is in a string, nothing really specific to dictionaries.

Comment: yea that's what I think.

Comment: Just put your "previously defined dictionaries" inside a master dictionary, then you can access one of those dictionaries with `master[found_item]`, and get a value from that dictionary with `master[found_item]['key_1']`

Comment: BTW, do your `import`s at the top of your script, not inside functions.

Comment: PM 2Ring had the answer. Maybe not to the question I asked, but to the question I wanted to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable via its name as string using `exec`:

```
dic1 = {'k': 'dic2'}
dic2 = {'key_1': 'value'}

exec('print ' + dic1['k'] + "['key_1']")
```

Answer (score -2):

Short answer: I don't think you can.

However, if the dictionary explore_items uses the dicts in questions as its keys, this should work.

ETA to clarify:

```
explore_items = {{dict1}: a, {dict2}:b, {dict3}:c}

random_key= random.choice(explore_items.keys())
```

Comment: Yes, you can using the random lib.

Comment: You _can_ do it, but you _really_ shouldn't.

Comment: @PM 2Ring Really shouldn't do what? Use the random lib? For what it's worth, your comment on the OP above answered my question. Is it good form to use your recommendation above?

Comment: @ParentalConsent The standard random module is perfectly good to use. My comment to mauve was in reference to the statement "I don't think you can." It _is_ actually possible to do _exactly_ what you asked for in your question: create a new variable that gets its name from a string. But it's almost never a good idea to do so, there are _much_ better ways (like the `master` dictionary I mentioned above).